# PostgreSQL opening other database failed

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql

Well, the problem is, when I close previous database and try to connect to the new one I get this:

```
Connection failed!
unterminated quoted string in connection info string
QPSQL:Unable to connect
```

Here full description of what I'am doing:

First I logging in with any avalible login and connect to the default "posgtres" database. Then I executing query `select * from pg_database;` to get list of all avalible databases. After that I close database.

```
void FdbToPg::connectToDatabase(){
    database.setHostName(ui.lineIP->text());
    database.setDatabaseName("postgres");
    database.setUserName(ui.lineLogin->text());
    database.setPassword(ui.linePassword->text());
    database.setPort(ui.linePort->text().toInt());

    QSqlQuery query;

    if(database.open()){
        QString dbOutput = "select * from pg_database;";
        query.exec(dbOutput);
        while(query.next()){
            ui.comboBox->addItem(query.value(0).toString(),QVariant::Char);
        }
        database.close();
    }else{
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Error", "Cant' connect ot the database");
    }

}
```

Then when on of the avalible databases been choosed I trying to connect to it. And there I get that error message

```
void FdbToPg::on_selectButton_clicked(){    
    database.setDatabaseName(ui.comboBox->itemData(ui.comboBox->currentIndex()).toString());
    database.setHostName(ui.lineIP->text());
    database.setUserName(ui.lineLogin->text());
    database.setPassword(ui.linePassword->text());
    database.setPort(ui.linePort->text().toInt());

    bool ok = database.open();

    if(ok != true){
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Connection", "Connection failed! \n" + database.lastError().text());
    } else {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Connection", "Connection worked!");     
    }
}
```

What's wrong here and how I properly suppose to close old database and open new one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT, but I'd guess it is preparing a connection string from the parameters you supply via those database.setXXX calls, and the resulting string has unbalanced quotes. Could one of the inputs you supply contains a stray quote char?

Comment: @harmic oh maybe you right I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem were here

```
 database.setDatabaseName(ui.comboBox->itemData(ui.comboBox->currentIndex()).toString());
```

`ui.comboBox->itemData(ui.comboBox->currentIndex()).toString()` were return an empty string. I changed it to  `database.setDatabaseName(ui.comboBox->currentIndex());` and now it's ok.

But I still don't understand whats wrong with 
`ui.comboBox->itemData(ui.comboBox->currentIndex()).toString()` command